# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException' GLKView

Tags: ios

I'm trying to build a new app out of pieces from another app. So I'm copying and pasting lots of stuff. I think that I have all of the code in place. It builds successfully but then crashes with this error:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[GLKViewController loadView] loaded the "2-view-17" nib but didn't get a GLKView.'`

Anyone have any suggestions as to what is missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your top view in the nib file of type `GLKView`? `GLKViewController` expects its view to be of this type. If you have several top-level views defined in the nib, make sure the `GLKView` is the first one.

Comment: That was it. It was still set as UIController. Thanks!